# Write to DataOutputStream from Java and reading it on C#

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I need to know how can I read input stream in C# from the following written bytes in Java:

```
// This is in the java client.
byte[] data = "some string".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeInt(data.length);
out.write(data);
out.flush();
```

The reason I'm asking this it's cause of the `writeInt(int)` method which I don't now how does it alters the sent bytes.

Comment: 1-Where's your C# code? 2-Did you tried anything? 3-If you already have a NetworkStream you can create a BinaryReader over it and use ReadInt32() and Read(byteCount)

Comment: DataOutputStream uses big endian, C# mostly likely uses little endian. You need to read big-endian.

Answer (score -2):

I have written a C# Conversion of Java's DataInputStream and DataOutputStream you can collect them here.

https://bitbucket.org/CTucker1327/c-datastreams/src

To construct these classes you would pass a BinaryWriter or BinaryReader into the constructor.

To Construct DataOutputStream

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BinaryWriter(Stream));
```

To Construct DataInputStream

```
DataInptuStream in = new DataInputStream(new BinaryReader(Stream));
```